# Using SOAP - How to debug XLM document request error

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I'm trying to retrieve info from the mindbody API using these examples they provide on gethub:
https://github.com/mindbody/API-Examples/tree/master/php

Specifically I am trying to run the demo code getClassDescriptions.php

I have the correct credentials and worked out those bugs, but now we are getting this error when sending the request:

```
Error Message : 
Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 1232). ---> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
```

How can I track down that string in that XML document?  I don't know if you would like to see the code that I'm using to send the request here.  If so, I can post it here.  Thanks for any help!  I'm three days into trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Use "track" option for soap client and then try/catch block around your call. In this block display $client->__getLastRequest() or $client->__getLastResponse().

Comment: do you have a link?  google is not helping me find out what the track option is....I'm a SOAP newbie.